# Breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions in a ForEach/ZStack (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a little problem on the lastest SwiftUI, the error is "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

My code is like that :

```
let cards = ["Azertyuiop", "Bzertyuiop", "Czertyuiop", "Dzertyuiop", "Ezertyuiop", "Fzertyuiop", "Gzertyuiop", "Hzertyuiop", "Izertyuiop", "Jzertyuiop", "Kzertyuiop", "Lzertyuiop", "Bzertyuiop", "Czertyuiop", "Dzertyuiop", "Ezertyuiop", "Fzertyuiop", "Gzertyuiop", "Lzertyuiop", "Bzertyuiop", "Czertyuiop", "Dzertyuiop", "Ezertyuiop", "Fzertyuiop", "Gzertyuiop", "Lzertyuiop", "Bzertyuiop", "Czertyuiop", "Dzertyuiop", "Ezertyuiop", "Fzertyuiop", "Gzertyuiop"]
   var body: some View {
       ScrollView{
         VStack (spacing: 0, content: {
           ForEach(0..<cards.count/3) { row in // create number of rows
               HStack (spacing: 0, content: {
                   ForEach(0..<3) { column in // create 3 columns
                     ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading){
                        Image("ghost").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                           .overlay(Rectangle().fill (LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.clear, .black]),startPoint: .center, endPoint: .bottom)).clipped())
                        Text(self.cards[row * 3 + column]) // this cause the error
                           .fontWeight(.semibold)
                     }
                   }
               })
            }
         })
       }
   }
```

I guess that the error comes from : row * 3 + column

So I tried to put the integer 1 instead of this calculation, and it worked. 
How to do this calculation in my body and my View? because SwiftUI does not allow me and shows me "Expected pattern"

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I run your code and I do not get any error, so, try to clean the build folder or update to the latest Xcode version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems. One is using ZStack with overlay, the other is Linear Gradient is a view and you can use it directly.

```
 ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading){
                Image("ghost").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.clear, .black]),startPoint: .center, endPoint: .bottom).clipped()
                Text(self.cards[row * 3 + column]) // this cause the error
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)

              }
```